# How to call a generic overloaded method

Tags: generics, c#-4.0

I have this method, lets call it A

```
public static List<string> GetDocuments<T>(T t, string documentType)
```

and an overload, lets call it B

```
public static List<string> GetDocuments(Guid id, string documentType)
{
   return GetDocuments(id, documentType);
}
```

The problem is that the call in B is to B meaning that it will recurse forever.  How do I call A in B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the following should be unambiguous:

```
public static List<string> GetDocuments(Guid id, string documentType)
{
   return GetDocuments<Guid>(id, documentType);
}
```